# Can anyone tell me if my choice is right? This is my last attempt

Tags: calculus

[image: I choose c]

because the left most rectangle is $f(-x) = -1$ 
height is still $1$ 
height of 2nd rectangle $f(-\pi/2)=0$
height of 3rd rectangle $f(0)=0$
right most rectangle $f(\pi/2)=0$

Comment: So which graph do you suppose to be the correct one?

Comment: @Andreas C looks correct to me but I am not sure

Comment: @Andreas I know b is wrong

Comment: Well, it says "$c_k$ is the left endpoint" so indeed C looks fine.